# Installing a Magento Extension manually via FTP or SSH

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, database

How to Install magento extensions manually. i had created a new database but i want to add

> classic theme

and

> augurio slide

extension. how to instally manually.
help me out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this tool http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php to download a given extension. Then unzip and do with as you please.

Comment: No problem :-) Glad to have been on help!

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has been asked, Magento market place has changed. You no longer need to use the link above to get the Zip file, you can now download magento extensions directly from - [Magento Market Place](https://marketplace.magento.com/)

Once you have the zip file, you can transfer the file across or use a little script I wrote to do it automatically - https://github.com/cameraki/Install-Magento-Extension-From-File